# MacOS Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Tags: java, macos, hadoop

Hadoop 3.0.0
MacOS High Sierra 10.13.3

When i run
`sbin/start-dfs.sh`

There has an error:
`Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable`

[image: bug describe]

I configured below but cannot work:

[image]

I also configured hadoop-env.sh with above variables, not work too.

Comment: Is that actually causing any error? Is your other code not running?

Comment: In fact, the hadoop service starts successfully. The error has not obstructed me use hadoop until now. I just want to solve this error.

Comment: It's not an error, though. And does not prevent any part of Hadoop from running successfully

Comment: @cricket_007 Ok, thank you sincerely.

Comment: I'm just asking... Does HDFS start? Can you show the full output of the command as text? Not an image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this error. I build the source code(hadoop-3.0.0-src.tar.gz).
Then i copy `hadoop-3.0.0-src/hadoop-dist/target/hadoop-3.0.0/lib/native` to `${HADOOP_HOME}/lib/native/`

I write an article for build Hadoop source code for macOS
https://medium.com/@zekexu/build-hadoop-source-code-on-macos-3f932780fd84
Hope helpful to you